# accessing elements of child html page from parent html page?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a html page main.html and it has a frame frame1 in which i am showing another html page child.html so basically child.html is the child of main.html and i want to change the value of text box which is in child.html after clicking on link which is in main.html. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the frame a name attribute, then `var frameDoc = window.frames[framename].document` should do the trick. You can then call any normal javascript commands like so: `frameDoc.whatever`

However, keep in mind that if the document inside the frame is from a different domain, you can't mess with it.